# How I can GetAsync in a thread safe manner (memoryCache) c#

Tags: c#, caching, xamarin.forms, memorycache

I am looking for a thread safe "GetAsync" version for memoryCache.

I know there is "GetOrCreateAsync" but before committing some data I need to check if it exists in the cache or not.

I have been googling but I have not found a ThreadSafe "GetAsync" method that I can use safely even where there are racing conditions.

Is there a version of "GetOrCreateAsync" but just GET?

Any suggestions?

UPDATE

In the end I used a GetOrAddAsync as below

```
  private readonly SemaphoreSlim locker = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);
    public async Task<T> GetOrAddAsync<T>(object key, Func<ICacheEntry, Task<T>> create)
    {
        await locker.WaitAsync();
        try
        {
            return await cache.GetOrCreateAsync(key, create);
        }
        finally
        {
            locker.Release();
        }
    }
```

I tested it like this

```
    var tasks = new List<Task>();
        var counter = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            var index = i;
            tasks.Add(Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                var x = await cache.GetOrAddAsync("test", entry => Task.FromResult(Interlocked.Increment(ref counter)));
                output.WriteLine($"Interaction {index} got {x}");
            }));
        }
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
        output.WriteLine("Counter {0}", counter);
        Assert.True(counter == 1);
    }
```

Is this test any good and prove race conditions will be handled?

Comment: There is no reason for memory cache to have `GetAsync` method, because there is nothing async that can be done on get. It's a memory cache so there is no IO to, for example, get cached value from external source such as database or file.

Comment: @Evk thanks for your explanation, I guess I am getting to grips with all this cache stuff and how it works. Could there be a scenario where in a race condition if you like the Get does not find the item as the add is still doing it?  I have a method that should only execute once and I add a "key" to cache e.g "ref123" but if called again I just need to search for "ref123" and if found dont execute method. hope makes sense

Comment: But isn't that exactly what `GetOrCreate` (or `GetOrCreateAsync` if that method to fetch value is async) does?

Comment: lets suppose I just want to cache a string value e.g "ref123" with 3 mins expiry time GetOrCreateAsync etc.. will always return me a value as it will create one if does not exists , what I need in simple terms in my scenario  that if a value does not exists  GetAsync will return null

Comment: Well just use `Get`, it will return null if it doesn't exists... But if you want to add an element IF it doesn't exists yet then `GetOrCreate` is what you need.

Comment: If you can't use `lock` because of `async/await` you may try `SemaphoreSlim` to prevent concurrent enters to protected from concurrency code part.

Comment: @aepot hi do you have a sample using it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SemaphoreSlim` powered lock.

For example you have a method that must be accessed only by single Thread at once, for example:

```cs
public async Task<MyData> GetDataAsync(string request); // not thread-safe!
```

An array of requests for data e.g.

```cs
string[] requests;
```

And you want to process these requests in parallel but do external call in a thread-safe manner using some method that performs the not safe call.

```cs
private async Task MakeRequestAsync(string request, SemaphoreSlim semaphore)
{
    await PrepareAsync();
    MyData data = null;

    await semaphore.WaitAsync(); // begin sync code
    try
    {
        data = await GetDataAsync(request);
    }
    finally
    {
        semaphore.Release();  // end sync code
    }

    if (data != null)
        await ProcessResultAsync(data);
}
```

```cs
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
using (SemaphoreSlim semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1)) // 1 = concurrency degree
{
    foreach (string request in requests)
        tasks.Add(MakeRequestAsync(request, semaphore));
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

Comment: @aeapot thanks for your code. Digesting it ,trying to put  a test together to prove that only a method is only executed once

Comment: Have you get success? You can share the solution here:).

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT I have not had success yet as I need to prove that it works and honestly struggling to get a test running to prove the point

Comment: Ok, you can also share your difficulty here when testing and we can help you.

Comment: @aepot thanks for your input I have adapted as you can see in the update section. How do you test this and prove it will work under race conditions?